# Как отправить сообщение в телеграм-чат?

Tags: telegram

С помощью телеграм-бота @myidbot переслал сообщение из своего телеграм-чата и получил

```
The chat ID of the forwarded message is: -1001550***136
```

Отправляю сообщение hello в бота которого я создал предварительно и указал токен бота и id чата 550***13 .Естественно, что диалога у бота с чатом до этого не было.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При отправке получаю ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде бот должен первым начать диалог с пользователем или чатом чтоб потом смочь пользователю или чату отправить сообщение. Но как заставить бота начать первым диалог с чатом?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите, чтобы бот отправил пользователю сообщение сам, без его согласия. Это невозможно

Comment: Если помог, поставь галочку, пожалуй

Comment: чтоб бот написал сообщение в мой. бота я в этот мой чат добавил